# Transfer a new package to another GitHub account

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I've forked a repository and made some change on it. Now I want to transfer/propose that to my organization so it will be part of the project.

That repository is a new package and it doesn't exist in my organization's GitHub in which I'm a member and not an admin.

Is there a way to do that using Linux command and through the GitHub's web interface?

I'm thinking about making kind of pull request but not to request changes because it is a new package/folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GitHub's web interface: at the top of the page of you repository there is a link «Settings»; click on it. At the bottom of the opened page there is a section «Transfer ownership»; click the button «Transfer» and choose a namespace to transfer to. The list of namespaces is the list of users and organizations you belong to and have rights to transfer the repo to.